# Postgresql psql command dumping error

Tags: postgresql, psql

im trying to export my table from Postgresql (RDS) on Amazon Web Services using the following command:

```
psql -t -A -F"," -c "select * from Album" > album.csv -h amazon-instance -p 5432 -U username -W -d chinook
```

I get this error message:

```
ERROR:  relation "album" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from Album
```

The reason for that error message is that my table starts with a capital (A)lbum so how can I escape my command to make this work?

Thank You

Comment: check if you have a table called `album` in your database

Comment: Yes I have this table but it starts with upper 'A' so postgres does not recognize the upper characters.

Comment: Search http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html for "quoting an identifier".

Comment: Bingo got it working, escaped my command like this:
-c "select * from "\""Album\""

Answer (score 3):

I had to escape the capital letter in the Album table on my psql command as follows:

```
psql -t -A -F"," -c "select * from "\""Album\"" > album.csv -h amazon-instance -p 5432 -U username -W -d chinook
```